# Laravel 5.6, Heroku and the Redis. Problems while deploying

Tags: laravel, heroku, redis

**Trouble:**

Running the Laravel project on localhost without any problems, but attempt to deploy it on the Heroku is insuccessful.

**Error:**

```
FatalThrowableError
Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "5.6.*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^5.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "~1.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "reliese/laravel": "^0.0.13",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**Heroku CLI (logged to Heroku bash tty):**

Here I tried to install composer dependencies and update them

```
~ $ composer install --dev && composer update
You are using the deprecated option "dev". Dev packages are installed by default now.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Package operations: 41 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/thanks (v1.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.5.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.7.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.8.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.7.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mockery/mockery (1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing filp/whoops (2.1.14): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing nunomaduro/collision (v1.1.22): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.3.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (4.3.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (3.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/version (2.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (3.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/object-reflector (1.1.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (3.0.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (2.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (3.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/environment (3.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/diff (3.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (2.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (6.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (2.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (6.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (1.7.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phar-io/version (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.7.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (7.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.6.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing reliese/laravel (v0.0.13): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing xethron/laravel-4-generators (3.1.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing xethron/migrations-generator (v2.0.2): Downloading (100%)
doctrine/cache suggests installing alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter (Required to use legacy MongoDB driver)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects suggests installing ext-soap (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.6.0)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^2.0)
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: darkaonline/l5-swagger
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/passport
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-permission
Discovered Package: xethron/migrations-generator
Package manifest generated successfully.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 5 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/thanks (v1.0.5 => v1.0.6): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating laravel/framework (v5.6.3 => v5.6.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating darkaonline/l5-swagger (5.6.1 => 5.6.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpseclib/phpseclib (2.0.9 => 2.0.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpspec/prophecy (1.7.4 => 1.7.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing predis/predis (v1.1.1): Downloading (100%)
predis/predis suggests installing ext-phpiredis (Allows faster serialization and deserialization of the Redis protocol) Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: darkaonline/l5-swagger
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/passport
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-permission
Discovered Package: xethron/migrations-generator
Package manifest generated successfully.

What about running composer thanks now?
This will spread some   by sending a ★  to the GitHub repositories of your fellow package maintainers.

~ $ ls vendor/|grep red
predis
```

As you see, redis folder is loaded successfully. But the Class **'Predis\Client' not found** is still happening!

After closing the bash and relogin again to the Heroku the redis folder is mystically gone :'(

```
~ $ exit

C:\Users\XTreme.ws
λ heroku run bash -a dfs-server
Running bash on dfs-server... up, run.7714 (Free)
~ $ ls vendor/|grep red
~ $
```

In Heroku Dashboard the project is successfully deployed without any errors.

So what am I doing wrong? Googled over the Internet and have no any solution for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

It was my fault: at one of the deployment steps I forgot to update my composer.lock with composer.json. Regenerating lock and pushing to my Heroku did the trick.